# RxJS filter and get first element - Typescript error

Tags: typescript, rxjs

```
getStep$(step): Observable<number> {
    return of([1,2,3]).pipe(
        filter((res: number) => step === res),
        first()
    ) as Observable<number>;
}
```

I expect for number. Like filter(res => res.step === step)[0]
But Webstorm throws typescript's error.

```
Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction<number>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<number[], number>'.   Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.     Type 'Observable<number[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<number>'.       Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You look for this, using `map` operator and not `filter`

```js
getStep$(step): Observable<number> {
    return of([1,2,3]).pipe(
        map((res: number[]) => res.filter((r) => step === r)[0])
    ) as Observable<number>;
}
```

The error you get is because you forgot to add [] to the type of the filter operator, and still this is not what you tried to achieve anyway.

```js
getStep$(step): Observable<number> {
    return of([1,2,3]).pipe(
        // HERE I ADDED [] to number
        filter((res: number[]) => step === res),
        first()
    ) as Observable<number>;
}
```